# OpenGL -- for a circle (stored in a VBO), when it is translated, where does the center lie?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Let's say I buffered a unit circle (from a triangle fan) that has a radius of one, and then I translate the object gltranslate(2,2,0). Where does that place the center of the circle? I come from a java graphics background where (x,y) represents the top left corner of an object.

Comment: You didn't say where the center of the circle was *before* the translate - nor, equivalently, what code you used to buffer the unit circle. Maybe it's implied that the center is at (0,0)?

Comment: Unit circle strong implies radius=1 and center (0,0). It might be an explicit condition of the unit circle, i dunno.

Comment: According to wikipedia, "**the** unit circle" "frequently" implies that the center is at (0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the modelview matrix was the identity prior to your `glTranslate()` call, and further assuming that your VBO circle was defined with respect to the origin, the circle's center will be at (2,2,0).

Comment: Thanks. I feel like an idiot asking such simplistic questions, but ogl is like chinese to me.